# How to insert Html anchor Tag around a specific word in C# webbrowser

Tags: c#

How to linkify a specific word in C# webbrowser on OnDocumentComplete event. I want to linkfy all the words say 'hemant' to hemant appears in the document in my c# browser. How to just add the anchor tag around any specific word using onDocumentComplete event?

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the HtmlDocument from the browser control and iterate the DOM and modify it.

Examples on using HtmlDocument can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx).

For iterating all elements check out the `All` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.all.aspx). For each HtmlElement check innerText or innerHTML for your word, and change accordingly to wrap it with an anchor.